# insert form data into mysql table

Tags: php, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, mysqli

I try to get form data into mysql table, but it wont work. The password and all what I *** is right. The checkbox and the country is now secondary.

> php:  Warning: sprintf(): Too few arguments
>
> Warning: mysqli::query(): Empty query

mysql table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'users' (
  'id'       INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  'username' VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  'password' VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  'email' VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
'firstname' VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
'lastname' VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
'phone' INT(255) NOT NULL,
'town' VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
'street' VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
'zip' INT(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ('id'),
  UNIQUE KEY 'username' ('username')
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    <?php


    $message = array();
    if (!empty($_POST)) {

        if (
            empty($_POST['f']['username']) ||                       
            empty($_POST['f']['password']) ||
            empty($_POST['f']['password_again']) ||
            empty($_POST['f']['email']) ||
            empty($_POST['f']['firstname']) ||          
            empty($_POST['f']['lastname']) ||
            empty($_POST['f']['phone']) ||
            empty($_POST['f']['town']) ||
            empty($_POST['f']['street']) ||
            empty($_POST['f']['zip']) 



        ) { 

            $message['error'] = 'Es wurden nicht alle Felder ausgefüllt.';
        } else if ($_POST['f']['password'] != $_POST['f']['password_again']) {
            $message['error'] = 'Die eingegebenen Passwörter stimmen nicht überein.';
        } else {
            unset($_POST['f']['password_again']);
            $salt = ''; 
            for ($i = 0; $i < 22; $i++) { 
                $salt .= substr('./ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789', mt_rand(0, 63), 1); 
            }
            $_POST['f']['password'] = crypt(
                $_POST['f']['password'],
                '$2a$10$' . $salt
            );

            $mysqli = @new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '***', '***');
            if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
                $message['error'] = 'Datenbankverbindung fehlgeschlagen: ' . $mysqli->connect_error;
            }
            $query = sprintf(
                "INSERT INTO user2 (username, password, email, firstname, lastname, phone, town, street, zip)
                SELECT * FROM (SELECT '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s') as new_user
                WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT username FROM user2 WHERE username = '%s'
                ) LIMIT 1;",
                $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['f']['username']),                               
                $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['f']['password']),                   
                $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['f']['email']),          
                $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['f']['firstname']),
                $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['f']['lastname']),
                $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['f']['phone']),
                $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['f']['town']),
                $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['f']['street']),
                $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['f']['zip'])             
            );
            $mysqli->query($query);
            if ($mysqli->affected_rows == 1) {
                $message['success'] = 'Neuer Benutzer (' . htmlspecialchars($_POST['f']['username']) . ') wurde angelegt, <a href="login.php">weiter zur Anmeldung</a>.';
                header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/socialad/login.php');
            } else {

            }
            $mysqli->close();
        }
    } 
?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <!-- Bootstrap -->
            <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <script type="text/javascript" type="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
            <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
            <!--[if lt IE 9]>


            <![endif]-->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>


    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="bs-example">
    <h1>Sign Up as a adsearcher</h1>
    <form action="./register1.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-3" for="username">Username:</label>
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                <input name="f[username]" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputusername" >
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-3" for="inputPassword">Password:</label>
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                <input name="f[password]" type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" >
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-3" for="confirmPassword">Confirm Password:</label>
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                <input name="f[password_again]" type="password" class="form-control" id="confirmPassword" >
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-3" for="inputEmail">Email:</label>
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                <input name="f[email]" type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" >
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-3" for="firstName">First Name:</label>
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                <input name="f[firstname]" type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" >
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-3" for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                <input name="f[lastname]" type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" >
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-3" for="phoneNumber">Phone:</label>
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                <input name="f[phone]" type="tel" class="form-control" id="phoneNumber" >
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-3" for="adress">Adress</label>

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-3" for="town">Town:</label>
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                <input name="f[town]" type="text" class="form-control" id="town" >
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-3" for="street">Street:</label>
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                <input name="f[street]" type="text" class="form-control" id="street" >

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-3" for="ZipCode">Zip Code:</label>
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                <input name="f[zip]" type="text" class="form-control" id="ZipCode" >
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-3" for="country">Country:</label>            
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <select class="form-control">

                    <option value="0">Please choose...</option>
                    <option value="0">--------------------------</option>
                                            <option value="221">United Kingdom</option>
                                            <option value="222">United States</option>


                                                            </select>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-9">
                <label class="checkbox-inline">
                    <input name="tos" value="accepted" type="checkbox">  I agree to the <a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a>.
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-9">
                <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary" >
                <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Reset">
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
</div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it's very clear that you have 10 `%s` and you provide only 9 arguments........

Comment: I delete one, the php warnings are away, but in my table are no values added.

Comment: Well this is a kind of problem with the mysql query that you have to investigate - what you want to insert and why it's not working. How can we know what are you posting? This is totally another question..

Comment: this was my question

Comment: This is the correct insert syntax: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp .. I don't understand your query - insert, then select, then inner select.... :|

Comment: Thank you for your help, but this worked in another version: $query = sprintf(
    "INSERT INTO users (username, password)
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT '%s', '%s') as new_user
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT username FROM user2 WHERE username = '%s'
    ) LIMIT 1;",
    $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['f']['username']),
    $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['f']['password']),
    $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['f']['username'])
   );